Dominated convergence theorem if $|f_n|^p\le g$ where $p\in [1,\infty)$
Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem. Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of complex valued measurable functions on a measure space $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$. Suppose that the sequence converges pointwise to a function $f$ and is dominated by some integrable function $g$ in the sense that $$|f_n(x)|\le g(x)$$ then $f$ is integrable and $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X|f_n-f|\;d\mu=0$$
My question is about whether we have that $$|f_n|^p\le g$$ on $X$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ where $p\in[1,\infty)$, we can conclude that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X |f_n-f|^p\;d\mu=0.$$
For me the answers is yes, Since we can completely retrace the proof for the $p=1$ case, but I'm not sure. Could anyone give me some confirmation or denial?

$|f_n-f|^{p} \leq 2^{p} (|f_n|^{p}+|f|^{p})\leq 2^{p+1}g$ a.e.. Apply DCT to $(|f_n-f|^{p})$
